# String is not null, empty, or empty string

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

What is the quickest and easiest way (in Classic ASP) to check if a string has some string (that has a length greater than 0) i.e. NOT "Null", "Nothing", "Empty", or '' *empty string*

Comment: Is there a String class in classic ASP?

Comment: @LajosArpad Classic ASP is not a language it is a technology that can handle server-side VBScript or Javascript code.  Therefore, VBScript does not have a string class (like .net/C#), but does have functionality to manipulate strings and variables.

Comment: If you have a string variable, as I understand your question, just test it with `Len(s) > 0`. If you need to verify your variable's _type_ to ensure it's a string, look to the (more complicated) answers below.

Comment: If you're always expecting a string just use `Len(s & "") > 0` avoids having to check for null values, similar to what @Bond is suggesting but with an implicit cast on the `s` variable.

Comment: Checking `s <> ""` is sufficient. It is also null proof since `null <> ""` is null which can be used inside `if` and the branch will not execute. It also works for types other than string... they are cast to string for comparison which is the safest cast and won't give you "type mismatch" errors.

Answer (score 8):

To make sure that the Variant you deal with is of sub-type "string", you need the VarType or TypeName function. To rule out zero length strings, you need Len(). To guard against strings of space, you could throw in a Trim().

Code to illustrate/experiment with:

```
Option Explicit

Function qq(s) : qq = """" & s & """" : End Function

Function toLiteral(x)
  Select Case VarType(x)
    Case vbEmpty
      toLiteral = "<Empty>"
    Case vbNull
      toLiteral = "<Null>"
    Case vbObject
      toLiteral = "<" & TypeName(x) & " object>"
    Case vbString
      toLiteral = qq(x)
    Case Else
      toLiteral = CStr(x)
  End Select
End Function

Function isGoodStr(x)
  isGoodStr = False
  If vbString = VarType(x) Then
     If 0 < Len(x) Then
        isGoodStr = True
     End If
  End If
End Function

Dim x
For Each x In Array("ok", "", " ", 1, 1.1, True, Null, Empty, New RegExp)
    WScript.Echo toLiteral(x), CStr(isGoodStr(x))
Next
```

output:

```
cscript 26107006.vbs
"ok" True
"" False
" " True
1 False
1.1 False
True False
<Null> False
<Empty> False
<IRegExp2 object> False
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's a one-liner that dodges all the trouble with `Null` by concatenating the value with an empty string.  It works for `Null`, `Empty`, `""`, and, of course, strings with actual length!  The only one it doesn't (nor shouldn't) work for is `Nothing`, because that's for object variables, of which a string is not.

```
isNullOrEmpty = (Len("" & myString) = 0)
```

Answer (score 4):

You could try having something like this:

```
Function nz(valToCheck, valIfNull)
 If IsNull(valToCheck) then
    nz = valIfNull
 Else
    nz = valToCheck
 End if
End function
```

and then you would use it like this:

```
if nz(var,"") <> "" then
  '--string has something in it
else
  '--string is null or empty
end is
```

Comment: It would be great if you can show a complete script rather than saying `--string has something in it`. That will help more users.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`VarType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3kfz157h%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) function to check if it is a string, then you can check if the string is not empty.  This statement will only pass through a string that isn't empty.

```
If VarType(MyString) = 8 Then
  If MyString <> "" Then 
    'String is Not Null And Not Empty, code goes here

  End If
End If
```

Comment: Please test your code before you post. VarType of "" and Trim(" ") is 8 (string). So your idea to check `VarType(MyString) > 1` is flawed.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner You're right thanks, i didn't notice that. Anyways, I fixed it.

Comment: Now numbers, booleans, and everything that Len() stringyfies will pass as 'good' strings.

Comment: `VarType` is still needed.

Comment: You shouldn't use And, but a nested If because VBScript evaluates both sub-expressions. For non-strings Len(MyString) is unnecessary/inefficient, for objects even fatal.

Comment: Thanks for going the extra mile (and the idea of comparing against "").

Comment: Who's answer is this now @Ekkehard.Horner?, I can barely recognise it. ;)

Comment: @Lankymart What can I say? The struggles of learning new technology risks forgetting the old.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
if mystring  = "" then wscript.echo "Empty string"
else wscript.echo "String is not empty"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%
Dim x,y
x = "abcdefg"

'counting length of string
y = Len(x) 
Response.Write (y)


'checking string is empty or not
If Len(x) = 0 then 
Response.Write ("<p>String is empty</p>")
Else
Response.Write ("<p>String is not empty</p>")
End If
%>
```

Hope this is helpful.